# Calculate Mean for elements of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of elements including five r coeffients for each gene:

```
my_list <- list(ENSG00000141956 = list(structure(0.158584641439316, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.351303636855506, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.144128203828052, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.276265507681158, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.1854938275357, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL))), ENSG00000141959 = list(
    structure(0.101822670837826, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        "expr", NULL)), structure(0.157722970392112, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.0370731638581523, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.176797462573245, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.0687982984906863, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL))), ENSG00000142149 = list(
    structure(-0.0736461404779602, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        "expr", NULL)), structure(0.0180832901610758, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.39674771703282, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.147951509051988, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.192000437181621, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL))), ENSG00000142156 = list(
    structure(0.1121937808055, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        "expr", NULL)), structure(-0.0358238958488585, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.240240771420854, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.0834552485519515, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(-0.118048173374175, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL))), ENSG00000142166 = list(
    structure(-0.0440487643391083, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        "expr", NULL)), structure(0.0419724287143289, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.155525788062941, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.195745293912149, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL)), structure(0.0197319683761103, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("expr", NULL))))
```

I want to convert `my_list` to a DataFrame where the rows are the element names (ENSGs) as `ID` and columns are the correspong r coeffiecients. Then, calculate the mean for each row to be restored in a new column `mean`. Also, compute the r.squared of column `mean` and restore it in a new column as `r2`.

I actually tried in this way that I stopped with this error:

```
my_list_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, my_list))
my_list_df$ID <- rownames(my_list_df)
rownames(my_list_df) <- NULL
my_list_df <- my_list_df[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]

my_list_df$mean <- rowMeans(my_list_df)

Error in base::rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

whould you help please!

UPDATE:

Following the @akrun's solution, here is the script to complete the task.

```
my_list_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, my_list))
my_list_df$ID <- rownames(my_list_df)
rownames(my_list_df) <- NULL
my_list_df <- my_list_df[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]

my_list_df[-1] <- unlist(my_list_df[-1])
my_list_df$mean <- rowMeans(my_list_df[-1])

## square the Mean column to get the r.squared values. 
options(scipen = 999)
my_list_df$r2 <- my_list_df[, "mean"]^2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the `my_list_df` is having `list` columns.  We may have to change it by `unlist`ing and assingning back the numeric columns to those and then do the `rowMeans` on the numeric columns

```
my_list_df[-1] <- unlist(my_list_df[-1])
rowMeans(my_list_df[-1])
[1]  0.148957632 -0.004624657  0.077046759 -0.039692762  0.073785343
```

---

Or using `map`

```
library(purrr)
colMeans(map_dfc(my_list, unlist))
ENSG00000141956 ENSG00000141959 ENSG00000142149 ENSG00000142156 ENSG00000142166 
    0.148957632    -0.004624657     0.077046759    -0.039692762     0.073785343
```